# Using the Sum Function with a case function based on criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, db2

Kind of new to SQL.  I have the below query and I need to modify it to sum Households best per DMA, where AverageHouseHoldIncome is greater than 75K per the dateendedstandard.  Conversely I would have to do the same thing for all AverageHouseholdIncomes less than 75k.  I have absolutely no idea how to do that.  I would appreciate any help with a bit of an explanation for the learning experience.

```
select c.KeyDMA as 'KeyDMA',
C.DMAName as 'DMAName',
a.DateEndedStandard as 'DateEndedStandard',
a.AverageHouseHoldIncome,
a.HouseholdsBest
from lookup..demographiccbg a
join InternalUseOnly..BlockGroupDMAMap  b on a.blockgroupfips = b.blockgroupfips
join lookup..dma c on b.keydma = c.keydma
where a.updoperation < 2
and b.updoperation < 2
and c.updoperation < 2
and c.updoperation < 2
and a.dateendedstandard = '12-31-2013'
```

Best,

Comment: Please tag the question with the appropriate RDBMS system.  SQL Server / MySQL etc so we can best answer your question.  Thanks!

Comment: You are probably looking for `GROUP` and `HAVING`, viz `SELECT x,y,z, SUM(AverageHouseHoldIncome) FROM ... WHERE .... GROUP BY x,y,z HAVING SUM(AverageHouseHoldIncome) > 75000`

Comment: Sorry Tags have been placed.

Comment: Well, which is it, SQL Server _or_ DB2, it (probably) can't be both.  Assuming `dateEndedStandard` _is_ a `DATE` type, you don't want to be using that format - it's culturally dependent, and can cause random failures/incorrect results - use the ISO format of `YYYY-MM-DD` instead (or on SQL Server, `YYYYMMDD`).  Ordering of ids shouldn't be relied upon - use something like `b.updOperation IN (0, 1)`.  Also, put as many conditions as possible into the relevant `JOIN` conditions, not in the `WHERE` clause (especially as this causes `LEFT JOIN`s to behave strangely).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
select c.KeyDMA as 'KeyDMA',
       C.DMAName as 'DMAName',
       a.DateEndedStandard as 'DateEndedStandard',
       SUM(
            CASE WHEN a.AverageHouseHoldIncome > 75000
                 THEN a.HouseholdsBest
                 ELSE NULL
            END
          ) as 'BestAbove75K',
       SUM(
            CASE WHEN a.AverageHouseHoldIncome <= 75000
                 THEN a.HouseholdsBest
                 ELSE NULL
            END
          ) as 'BestLess75K'
  from lookup..demographiccbg a
  join InternalUseOnly..BlockGroupDMAMap  b on a.blockgroupfips = b.blockgroupfips
  join lookup..dma c on b.keydma = c.keydma
  where a.updoperation < 2
    and b.updoperation < 2
    and c.updoperation < 2
    and a.dateendedstandard = '12-31-2013'
  GROUP BY 
           c.KeyDMA,
           C.DMAName,
           a.DateEndedStandard
```